# Is a question about how many times a sci-fi live action has changed directors allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask how many times an anime/sci fi live action which is in pre-production have changed directors already. I've read other topics here about making production questions (like behind the scenes) but I don't have it clear. Is it allowed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Sure.

Behind-the-scenes information is [explicitly on-topic according to the help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and so is "trivia" such as how many times a film has changed directors. This kind of information is part of what a fan might be interested in, and it's on-topic to ask about it (provided it's sci-fi or fantasy, of course).

Comment: Agreed, with the provision that answers must be good SE answers (full, complete, and detailed).

Comment: Interesting. If it was where I think it should be (M&TV), it'd be closed as trivia. There's nothing in the SFF help center about 'trivia'?

Comment: @Mazura If there is, it'd just be saying that trivia is on-topic :-) A large proportion of the questions on this site are (or could be argued to be) trivia. Incidentally, there's a [two-year-old consensus](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1809/27759) on M&TV that trivia *shouldn't* be on-topic, which I support since "trivia" is an inherently difficult concept to define rigorously enough for a close reason.

Answer (score 1):

While the subject is on topic (see Rand al'Thor's answer), simply asking for a list of movies that have changed directors during pre-production may be closed as off topic because it asks for a (potentially very large) list of works. Try to phrase the question so that it can have a definitive answer rather than asking for an open-ended list.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about a specific movie

Comment: @KutuluMike is right, and you can see the question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/164075/31394).

Comment: @Randal'Thor That's good. I read the Meta question as being about how many times **any** anime/sci fi live action movie has changed director's in pre-production.